# Hook for URL admin/people/create

Tags: hooks

What is the hook to alter the form that appears for the URL admin/people/create?

I tried `hook_form_alter()`, but that's not the right one.

Comment: I think you made a mistake somewhere, I can't think of a reason why hook_form_alter wouldn't work for that particular form.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case "user_register_form" :
      //Your Logic
    break;
  }
}
```

But for performance issue use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Comment: For future readers: The implementation of `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` for user_register_form would be `hook_form_user_register_form_alter()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function modulename_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form) {
  // modify $form var
}
```

[`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` API Docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Comment: The complete list of parameters would be `&$form, &$form_state, $form_id`; if the function is just using the first parameter (as it normally happen), it can short the parameter list to only that parameter.